# capture image from IP camera through ffmpeg in command line or opencv getting a gray image

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, rtsp, ip-camera

Now I have a IP camera. I tried to get a image through ffmpeg (like this : ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -i "my rtsp stream address" -y -f image2  test.jpg ).That's OK! Or I tried to do this through opencv,no problem too.But when I open the stream in vlc,At the same time,I tried to capture the image ,oh,I just got a gray image.
  why? if I open the stream in vlc two times,that's also OK! If capturing the image and view the rtsp stream together,just got a gray image.Is the reason of IP camera?[normal image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmCtS.jpg)[gray image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dbjy.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this https://gist.github.com/jamek/1dda2add62b3f7ac415a

`g++ -s -o ffmpeg_rtsp rtsp.cpp -lavcodec -lavutil -lswscale -lavformat`

Run: `./ffmpeg_rtsp "your rtsp stream address"`

Comment: sorry,when i compile rtsp.cpp ,there is a problem.‘av_frame_alloc’ was not declared in this scope

Comment: Thank you very much!! I change the av_frame_alloc to the avcodec_alloc_frame and it works.

Comment: I am sorry to say the result of this program is also not very good,some of capturing images,at the beginning,is OK.about 20 images.but the rest of the capturing images are cover with mosaic

Comment: it's just example, in work we use more efficient way to save stream with verification of frames

Comment: Thank you in any case.this is my first quesition in stackoverflow and even first view this site.without you help,I can't know how to call this ffmpeg functions,thank you